# Не могу подключить таблицу стилей к html

Tags: html

Создаю свой сайт.Пытаюсь протестировать подключение css таблиц стилей но когда захожу в браузер ничего не меняется. index.html и style.css в одной дериктории в styles.css у меня записано так h1 {color:green;}

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
     <title>CSS test</title> 
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head> 
<body> 
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: style.css или styles.css?

Comment: проверьте 1) правильно ли указали имя файла со стилями 2) находится ли он в корне, также вы бы привели этот файл отдельно - в нем только 1 строчка? она именно так записана как вы ее привели?

Comment: Во-первых я несколько раз проверил имя файла совпадает, в файле одна строчка так как я её записал. Вот мой алгоритм создания сайта: 1)В корне создаю папку website в нёй создаю файл index.html и styles.css

Answer (score 0):

Может помочь, если сделаешь ссылку абсолютной. Пример (C:\Users\Владелец\Desktop...)

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код в том виде, в котором Вы привели его в вопросе однозначно рабочий и проблема не в нем.
Похоже на то, что браузер по какой-то причине не видит Ваш css-файл, который Вы создали. Из личной практики, это может быть:

1. Скорее всего, ошибка в имени css-файла, если он точно лежит в той же папке website. Проверьте, точно ли у него расширение css, а не txt, к примеру (у Вас должны отображаться расширения всех файлов в настройках проводника Windows)?
2. Как вариант (хоть и маловероятно), что-то в настройках доступа в самой Windows. Чисто теоретически, если Вы вдруг не под учеткой Администратора работаете, это возможно, но вряд ли. Попробуйте перенести вместе оба Ваших файла в другую папку.
3. Пару раз сталкивался с тем, что в редакторе кода один из файлов (html или css) банально забыли сохранить. Проверьте.

А в идеале, скриншот Вашей папки website посмотреть бы, для полноты картины...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить ~/ в начале пути или сделать так

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/Site.css" />
</head>
```